# Completion of proof of curvature formula (3D)

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry, vector-analysis, curvature

Schaum's Outline of Vector Calculus Problem 3.54 states:

> Prove that the curvature of the space curve $\mathbf{r}=r(t)$ is given numerically by $\kappa=\dfrac{|\dot{r}\times \ddot{r}|}{|\dot{r}|^3}$ where dots denote differentiation with respect to $t$.

In 2D, the formula is [terrible, but barely comprehensible.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/275248/deriving-curvature-formula/275324#275324) At least from there it's evident how you'd argue the existence of the cross product term in the original expression.

The question however, seems to suggest probably a formula consistent in 3D. Here's my reasoning:

\begin{align*}
\dfrac{ds}{dt} &= |\dot{r}| \\
\hat{T} &= \dfrac{\dfrac{d\vec{r}}{dt}}{\dfrac{ds}{dt}} = \dfrac{\dot{r}}{|\dot{r}|} \\ \\
\dfrac{d}{dt}\dfrac{1}{|\dot{r}|} &= \dfrac{d}{dt}(\dot{r}\cdot\dot{r})^{-\frac12}=-\dfrac{\dot{r}\cdot\ddot{r}}{|\dot{r}|^3} \\ \\
\dfrac{d\hat{T}}{ds} &=\dfrac{\ddot{r}}{|\dot{r}|^2}-\dfrac{\dot{r}(\dot{r} \cdot \ddot{r})}{|\dot{r}|^4} \tag*{$\left(\dfrac{d\hat{T}}{ds}=\dfrac{\frac{d\hat{T}}{dt}}{\frac{ds}{dt}}\right)$}\\
&= \dfrac{\ddot{r}(\dot{r}\cdot\dot{r})-\dot{r}(\dot{r} \cdot \ddot{r})}{|\dot{r}|^4} \\
\dfrac{d\hat{T}}{ds} \cdot \dfrac{d\hat{T}}{ds} &= \dfrac{(\ddot{r} \cdot \ddot{r})(\dot{r}\cdot\dot{r})^2+(\dot{r}\cdot\dot{r})(\dot{r} \cdot \ddot{r})^2-2(\dot{r}\cdot\ddot{r})(\dot{r}\cdot\dot{r})(\dot{r}\cdot\ddot{r})}{|\dot{r}|^8} \\
&= \dfrac{(\dot{r}\cdot\dot{r})\Bigl((\ddot{r} \cdot \ddot{r})(\dot{r}\cdot\dot{r})-(\dot{r}\cdot\ddot{r})^2\Bigr)}{|\dot{r}|^8} \\
&= \dfrac{(\ddot{r} \cdot \ddot{r})(\dot{r}\cdot\dot{r})-(\dot{r}\cdot\ddot{r})^2}{|\dot{r}|^6} \\
\left|\dfrac{d\hat{T}}{ds}\right| &= \dfrac{\sqrt{(\ddot{r} \cdot \ddot{r})(\dot{r}\cdot\dot{r})-(\dot{r}\cdot\ddot{r})^2}}{|\dot{r}|^3}
\end{align*}

That's as much as I could do short of conjuring matrices from thin air. Most of it looks done, but I need help where I'm stuck. This specifically:

> $\sqrt{(\ddot{r} \cdot \ddot{r})(\dot{r}\cdot\dot{r})-(\dot{r}\cdot\ddot{r})^2} = |\dot{r} \times \ddot{r}|$

My amateur guess is that maybe $(\ddot{r} \cdot \ddot{r})(\dot{r}\cdot\dot{r})-(\dot{r}\cdot\ddot{r})^2=(\dot{r}\times\ddot{r})\cdot(\dot{r}\times\ddot{r})$ (strategy worked well for me the whole way anyway) but I have no idea what to do with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your guess
$$
(\ddot{r} \cdot \ddot{r})(\dot{r}\cdot\dot{r}) - (\dot{r}\cdot\ddot{r})^{2} = (\dot{r}\times\ddot{r})\cdot(\dot{r}\times\ddot{r}),
$$
which may be rewritten
$$
\|\ddot{r}\|^{2}\, \|\dot{r}\|^{2} - (\dot{r}\cdot\ddot{r})^{2} = \|\dot{r}\times\ddot{r}\|^{2},
$$
is an example of [*Lagrange's identity*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_identity) for the cross product.

If $\theta$ denotes the angle between $\dot{r}$ and $\ddot{r}$, and we recall
\begin{align*}
  \dot{r}\cdot\ddot{r} &= \|\dot{r}\|\, \|\ddot{r}\| \cos\theta, \\
  \|\dot{r}\times\ddot{r}\| &= \|\dot{r}\|\, \|\ddot{r}\| \sin\theta,
\end{align*}
the rewritten identity may further be seen as an instance of $1 - \cos^{2}\theta = \sin^{2}\theta$.

Comment: I ran with the hint you gave at the end and I got this:
$\begin{align*}
\left\|\ddot{r}\right\|^2\left\|\ddot{r}\right\|^2 - (\dot{r}\cdot\ddot{r})^2 &= \left\|\ddot{r}\right\|^2 \left\|\ddot{r}\right\|^2 - \left\|\dot{r}\right\|^2\left\|\ddot{r}\right\|^2\cos^2(\theta) \\
&= \left\|\ddot{r}\right\|^2\Bigl(\left\|\ddot{r}\right\|^2-\left\|\dot{r}\right\|^2\cos^2\theta\Bigr) \\
&= \left\|\ddot{r}\right\|^2\Bigl(\left\|\ddot{r}\right\|^2-\left\|\dot{r}\right\|^2+\left\|\dot{r}\right\|^2\sin^2\theta\Bigr)
\end{align*}$

Comment: In order for it to align with the cross product term, I'd then have to prove that $\left\|\ddot{r}\right\|^2=\left\|\dot{r}\right\|^2$.
Is this right or have I made a mistake somewhere?

Comment: My oops: In the second line there was a double dot that should have been a dot.

Comment: Oh yeah that clears that up, thanks!

Comment: For complete clarity for anyone else, this is what the proper working out looks like:
$\begin{align*} \left\|\ddot{r}\right\|^2\left\|\dot{r}\right\|^2 - (\dot{r}\cdot\ddot{r})^2 &= \left\|\ddot{r}\right\|^2 \left\|\dot{r}\right\|^2 - \left\|\dot{r}\right\|^2\left\|\ddot{r}\right\|^2\cos^2(\theta) \\ &= \left\|\ddot{r}\right\|^2\Bigl(\left\|\dot{r}\right\|^2-\left\|\dot{r}\right\|^2\cos^2\theta\Bigr) \\ &= \left\|\ddot{r}\right\|^2\left\| \dot{r}\right\|^2\sin^2\theta \end{align*}$